# Parsing tokens in strings

Tags: c#, string, token

*Note: I'm using the word "token", but I'm not sure it's the correct term for this kind of stuff.*

I have a string, with tokens, that looks something like this: `I'm {name}, blablabla {a:foo} and {a,b : bar}`.

So each token is surrounded by `{}` and can have some settings (comma separated list) before a `:`. So each tokens looks like either `{id}` or `{set,tings:id}`. It's possible that there is some extra whitespace in there too: `{ set, tings : id }`.

Now I have objects that provide these id's. So for instance I have 2 objects, one with the id `name == "Jef"` and another with `name == "An"`. But in reality I have many many objects. The objects have a `string getValue(string id)` method. The values of the id's are always strings. And I also have a few methods that correspond to these settings. So for example if `lower` is one of the settings, the final result will be all lower letters. In the end I need all tokens to be filled with the values behind the id's and the needed settings to be applied.

I only have a few of these strings, but they need to be filled by many many different object. So I was wondering what a good way of parsing this would be? With some kind of pre-processing, so that the string should only be interpreted once and can then be filled many times very quickly.

At the moment I'm using a combination of regex to get the stuff between `{}` and then parse that with completely custom code. I also just parse the string again every time I want to fill it with the values, but this looks a bit ugly. So if there is a nicer way of doing this, perhaps even some (buildin) library, that would be great.

*Note: I'm using the `{a,b:id}` scheme because I like how it looks, but if there is a better way of representing these tokens in my string I'm fine with that. However, some of the strings are urls so I can't use `/` or something as delimiters.*

---

My current code:

```
public class Token
{
    private string _id;
    public string ID { get { return _id; } }

    private string _settings;

    public Token(string token)
    {
        if (token.Contains(":"))
        {
            int separator = token.IndexOf(":");
            _settings = token.Substring(0, separator).Trim();
            _id = token.Substring(separator+1).Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            _id = token.Trim();
        }
    }

    public string GetValueFrom(CardInfo cardInfo)
    {
        string value = cardInfo.GetById(_id).Value; // GetById returns a wrapper for string for some reason, but .Value always gives a string.
        if (_settings != null && _settings.Contains("e"))
        {
            value = WWW.EscapeURL(value); //WWW from Unity
        }

        return value;
    }
}



private static readonly Regex TOKEN_REGEX = new Regex(@"{(.+)}");

public static IEnumerable<Token> GetAllTokensFrom(string text)
{
    return TOKEN_REGEX.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(m => new Token(m.Groups[1].Value));
}

public static string FillAllTokensIn(string text, CardInfo info)
{
    return TOKEN_REGEX.Replace(text, m => TranslateToken(m.Groups[1].Value, info));
}

private static string TranslateToken(string value, CardInfo card)
{
    Token token = new Token(value);
    return token.GetValueFrom(card);
}
```

Note: I currently only have the setting "e", so I don't actually parse the settings *yet* as a comma-separated list.

Comment: You question is a little vague and broad as it stands. Can you provide more concrete examples and share some of the code you have.

Comment: @MattBurland I added my current code. It's been put together quickly, so far from great at the moment.

Comment: `...but this is a little slow` - please, define `slow`. How slow is it and what do you expect?

Comment: Well I haven't done any real performance testing, so actually it was wrong to say it is slow. But it does feel not-right that the code has to match/replace with regex over the string every time I want to fill or get the tokens. Seems like there should be a nicer way. I've updated my question to rephrase this to my real problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [FastReplacer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/298519/Fast-Token-Replacement-in-Csharp) found on Codeproject